# mql4 bollingers bands always give the same value

Tags: mql4, mql

bollingers bands always give the same value and give the same value in each symbol there is no error in the code sequence but there is a logical error can you help

```
property copyright "Copyright 2024, MetaQuotes Ltd."
property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
property version   "1.00"
property strict
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
{

double bb_degeri = iBands(NULL,PERIOD_CURRENT,21,0,2,PRICE_CLOSE);
Alert("");
Alert(bb_degeri);
```

it needs to give a different value for each symbol and the forex bot I will write will open and close trades according to these values

Comment: Check the official documentation of MQL5 to see the approach used. You need an indicator handler to be declared initially, then use it to obtain data. In your example you just declared the handler (it can be of type `int`). Check the examples, e.g. MACD Sample EA to see how handler is declared and used in MQL5. 
Please remove MQL and MQL4 tags to avoid confusion

Comment: @DanielKniaz Can you guide me where I can access these official documents?

Comment: https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/indicators/ibands has both documentation and example

Answer (score 0):

Your question states MQL4, your code looks more like MQL5, you need to clarify which language you are using as they are distinctly different.

MQL4 is relitevly straight forward, check the documentation:
[iBands](https://docs.mql4.com/indicators/ibands)

Values are retrieved using the following code

```
double value=iBands(NULL,0,20,2,0,PRICE_LOW,MODE_LOWER,0);
```

MQL5 requires a handler. Again check the documentation:
[iBands](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/indicators/ibands)

Example:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
   handle_iBands = iBands(_Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT, 20, 0, 0.21, PRICE_OPEN);
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnCalculate(const int rates_total,
                const int prev_calculated,
                const datetime &time[],
                const double &open[],
                const double &high[],
                const double &low[],
                const double &close[],
                const long &tick_volume[],
                const long &volume[],
                const int &spread[])
{
   int max=rates_total; //rates_total;
   CopyBuffer(handle_iBands, 0, 0, max, Upper);
   CopyBuffer(handle_iBands, 0, 0, max, Lower);
   double value1=Upper[0];
   double value2=Lower[0];
return(rates_total);
}
```